# Configurable Map Viewer Documentation Broken Links

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

The documentation page at

http://docs.cmv.io/en/1.3.4/

has broken links

For instance if you click viewer.js here:

http://docs.cmv.io/en/1.3.4/configure/viewer/

The links do not work (or at least I have an issue)

Is there a way to download an offline version of documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue. I guess there is not much you can do about that.

Well, there is: one can also [contribute](http://docs.cmv.io/en/1.3.4/contribute/)!

> Is there a way to download an offline version of documentation?

You can download the documentation (markdown) from its own repo: https://github.com/cmv/cmv-docs

There is not a provided pdf build of the documentation. In that case, you could have the chance to download it by clicking in the lower left corner, where it says *Read the Docs*.